# Social share buttons in footer

Tags: css, html-lists, footer, css-tables

I have problem positioning the buttons (social share b.) in the footer. They're nearly in the middle but still are a bit on the right. How to set the in the middle ?

This code is in the footer.php :

```css
.footer-social { text-align:center;}
.footer-social li {display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social">
    <ul>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/133/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-09-24.png' /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/136/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-30-24.png' /></a></li>        </ul>
</div>
```

And this is in the css:

.footer-social { text-align:center;}
.footer-social li {display:inline;}

Comment: Set `margin:0` and `padding:0` in the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin:0` and `padding:0` in the `<ul>`

```css
ul{ margin:0; padding: 0;}
.footer-social { text-align:center;}
.footer-social li {display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social">
    <ul>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/133/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-09-24.png' /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/136/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-30-24.png' /></a></li>        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer-social { text-align:center;}
.footer-social li {display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social">
    <ul>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/133/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-09-24.png' /></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/136/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-30-24.png' /></a></li>        </ul>
</div>
```